# c# First monthletter in uppercase

Tags: c#, date-format

I'm displaying a month name like this:

```
String.Format("{0:MMMM}", DateTime.Now)
```

However, when using Swedish all month names are in lowercase.

Is there some neat trick to make first letter uppercase when formatting dates? Or do I have to write a function for it?

Comment: in swedish monthnames are written in all lower-case. Why would you wan't to use a diffrent formatting? Is it that it is the first word in a sentence? In that case it's not date formatting anymore...

Comment: "If a date occurs at the beginning of a sentence, it isn't date formatting."  How do you work that out?

Comment: You can use this "MMMM" format to obtain the First letter of month in uppercase:

DateTime dt = new DateTime(2008, 3, 9, 16, 5, 7, 123);
String.Format("{0:dddd, MMMM d, yyyy}", dt);  // "Sunday, March 9, 2008"

For more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

[![I tried it in this web: https://rextester.com/][1]][1]

It will put in the date language of your server.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are some good answers here already. If you want a function you can write:

```
char.ToUpper(s[0]) + s.Substring(1);
```

Comment: Use TextInfo.ToTitleCase() instead.

Answer (score 17):

I'd suggest to clone a culture and re-define a new month names in it:

```
var swedish = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("sv-SE");
swedish = (CultureInfo)swedish.Clone();
swedish.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames =
    swedish.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames
        .Select(m => swedish.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(m))
        .ToArray();

swedish.DateTimeFormat.MonthGenitiveNames =
    swedish.DateTimeFormat.MonthGenitiveNames
        .Select(m => swedish.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(m))
        .ToArray();
```

and then use it in `string.Format` method:

```
// date holds "Mars"
var date = String.Format(swedish, "{0:MMMM}", DateTime.Now);
```

To make months in upper case I use [`TextInfo.ToTitleCase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase.aspx) method.

Comment: Nice! It was very usefull to me because I needed to work with months too many times in my code, so using Substring would be very annoying.

Comment: It's the same practically as I proposed before xD! I don't know why mine has negative votes...

Comment: This worked excellent for me in my .NET MAUI app! Thank you